# Linux Centos upgrade glibc 2.12 to 2.14 config error

Tags: linux, centos, glibc, automake

I am attempting to upgrade 2.12 to 2.14 on Centos and have been following this example: [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.12 to 2.14 on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos)

All has worked up to `../configure --prefix=/usr/share/doc/glibc-2.14` when I get the output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/root/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Output of core tests in config.log:

```
configure:2363: checking build system type
configure:2377: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2397: checking host system type
configure:2410: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2479: checking for gcc
configure:2509: result: no
configure:2572: checking for cc
configure:2619: result: no
configure:2675: checking for cl.exe
configure:2705: result: no
configure:2729: error: in `/root/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build':
configure:2731: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Thanks for any help with this :)

Comment: What does `which gcc` produce? What does `gcc --version` produce?

Comment: Please show the relevant results from `config.log`.

Comment: You cannot compile a source code without a compiler. You will need to install `gcc`, `make`, `automake`, `autoconf`, `binutils`, `glibc-headers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear you are missing a C compiler, for example

`checking for gcc... no`

I would suggest starting with Employed Russian's questions:

Does `gcc --version` run and report a version number? If no, continue.

Does `which gcc` give you a path?  If no, continue

If either of the above are yes, I would suggest reviewing the contents of your $PATH variable.

If both are no, try:

`sudo yum group install "Development Tools"`

... with or without sudo, as needed.