# how to add custom path for rpm dependencies

Tags: linux, rpm

I am trying to install some software that's required `glib 2.14`

so I installed it with this tutorial: [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.12 to 2.14 on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos)

the problem is `glib 2.14` path is `/opt/glibc-2.14/lib/libc.so.6`

so when I try to install software using rpm i still getting this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by xyz-4.6.6-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by xyz-4.6.6-1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is needed by xyz-4.6.6-1.x86_64
```

how can I add the custom path for rpm dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

It would help a bit if you gave us the name of the package you are trying to install. You can't just provide a path, RPM checks if it's got any packages on record that provide these libraries, and there aren't any. Here are a couple methods you could use:

1. Use `--nodeps`

   If you already know that you have everything that is required, using `--nodeps` is completely fine IMO.
2. Create virtual packages for the missing libraries (**advanced**)

   You are missing the following libraries: `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)` `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)` `libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)`.

   Here's an example `.spec` file to create a virtual package that **claims** to provide these libraries:

   ```
   Name: libc-virtual-provides
   Provides: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
   Provides: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
   Provides: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
   Version: 1.0
   Release: 1
   Summary: Virtual package providing libc 2.14, 2.15, 2.17
   License: Public domain

   %description
   Virtual package providing libc 2.14, 2.15, 2.17

   %prep

   %files

   %changelog
   ```

   To create a virtual package from this SPEC file, first create some directories:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/BUILD ~/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT ~/rpmbuild/RPMS ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES ~/rpmbuild/SPECS ~/rpmbuild/SRPMS
   ```

   Then copy the SPEC file into `~/rpmbuild/SPECS`, and build an RPM:

   ```
   cp virtual-glibc-provides.spec ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
   cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
   rpmbuild -ba virtual-glibc-provides.spec
   ```

   You'll get output like this:

   ```
   Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.6Jni5u
   + umask 022
   + cd /home/.../rpmbuild/BUILD
   + exit 0
   Processing files: glib2.14-virtual-provides-2.14-1.x86_64
   Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/.../rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/glib2.14-virtual-provides-2.14-1.x86_64
   Wrote: /home/.../rpmbuild/SRPMS/glib2.14-virtual-provides-2.14-1.src.rpm
   Wrote: /home/.../rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/glib2.14-virtual-provides-2.14-1.x86_64.rpm
   Executing(%clean): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.YNj8gP
   + umask 022
   + cd /home/.../rpmbuild/BUILD
   + /bin/rm -rf /home/.../rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/glib2.14-virtual-provides-2.14-1.x86_64
   + exit 0
   ```

   And you'll have your RPM under `/home/.../rpmbuild/RPMS/`, which you can then install using `rpm -ivh ....rpm`. You should then be able to install the other package without any problems.