# How to install latest glibc (version 2.29) beside system installed one & compile a program?

Tags: c, glibc

Based on This [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos) link I downloaded & installed **glibc v2.29** in "/usr/local/glibc" path of Linux OS. Then based on this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) link I tried to compile This [Example](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/31557/c11-threads-simple-example), But I got following errors. 
**First Try Command:**

> gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

**First Try Error Log:**

```
main.c:1:10: fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
#include <threads.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**Second Try Command:**
In second try, I am using **"-I"** & **"-L"** GCC command options.

> gcc -Wall -g -I/usr/local/glibc/include -o main main.c -L/usr/local/glibc/lib -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

**Second Try Error Log:**

```
/tmp/ccCNYemW.o: In function `main':
/home/.../main.c:14: undefined reference to `thrd_create'
/home/.../main.c:16: undefined reference to `thrd_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I don't know where is the problem. Please Help me.

Comment: Should the second try have a `-Wl,-lthread` or similar to link in the thread library?

Comment: What is the "-lthread"? And What is the correct value for "-lthread"? I mainly write my programs in GO & Now trying to learn c, because I like C too.

Comment: Building and installing an alternative glibc is not hard, but actually *using* it can be very troublesome, not least because in a glibc-based system, pretty much every tool and other library in the entire system depends on glibc.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize `thrd_create` ... came from libc.  You might try installing into a `docker` container

Comment: Are you sure `glibc 2.29` on your machine comes with `thrd_create`? Can you check if `/usr/local/glibc/lib/libc.so.6` has the symbol enabled? You might be more interested in the `--sysroot` option for gcc, or just create a chroot.

Comment: Yes I am sure, There is "threads.h" file in "include" folder. This is new standard thread library as glibc v2.28. I don't know what do you mean by "Can you ... libc.so.6 has the symbol enabled?", But There is a symlink "libc.so.6" to "libc-2.29.so" & What is the use case for "--sysroot" option?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't put an alternate libc (or alternate version of your libc) in a path searched by the normal include and library search (both link-time and runtime library search) for your main system one. This is a recipe for disaster. Installing a different glibc in `/usr/local/` does avoid clobbering your system one, but now you just have two installed in places where the same tools can see and use them.

To do this right, you really need a full separate toolchain (gcc, binutils) in some completely separate path (like `~/my_glibc_root/...` or `/opt/alt_glibc_root/...`). I'm not sure if there's a recommended way to do this. The glibc build procedures in Linux From Scratch might be a good place to look for ideas. In theory it *can* be done in a single stage; I do that with musl libc in [musl-cross-make](https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make) by careful use of intermediate make rules in the gcc build system. But applying the same idea to glibc probably requires some extra care.

Comment: What is the default locations for gcc to search for libraries?

Comment: I install glibc in "/opt/glibc" this time but This does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

> Second Try Command: In second try, I am using "-I" & "-L" GCC command options.
>
> `gcc -Wall -g -I/usr/local/glibc/include -o main main.c -L/usr/local/glibc/lib -Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/glibc/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

This command is *almost* correct. The `thrd_create` and `thrd_join` functions are defined in `libpthread`, which you *didn't* link against.

Add `-pthread` to your compile command, and the link should succeed.

P.S. R's advice of not installing alternate GLIBC into `/usr/local` is also a good one.