# conflicting types for '__readlink' during make glibc 2.14

Tags: glibc

I made a softwareupdate on a simulationsoftware which needs a newer version of glibc. Therefore I wanted to install the glibc version 2.14 on a new prefix.

According to [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.12 to 2.14 on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos/38317265#38317265)
i tried to install it on a sles11sp3

```
mkdir /var/mpi/Libraries/glibc_install; cd /var/mpi/Libraries/glibc_install
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.14
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/var/mpi/Libraries/glibc-2.14
make -j4
```

During the make I get the following error:

```
readlink.c:26: error: conflicting types for ‘__readlink’
../include/unistd.h:120: error: previous declaration of ‘__readlink’ was here
make[2]: *** [/var/mpi/Libraries/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/build/io/readlink.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/mpi/Libraries/glibc_install/glibc-2.14/io'
make[1]: *** [io/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/mpi/Libraries/glibc_install/glibc-2.14'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you have a clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`io/readlink.c` is just a stub implementation which always fails at run time.  It is not supposed to be compiled at all when building for GNU/Linux.  Instead, the implementation should come from the generic system call wrapper in `sysdeps/unix/syscalls.list`:

```
readlink     -       readlink        i:spi   __readlink      readlink
```

However, recent Linux architectures (those called `generic` in Linux parlance, currently aarch64, csky, nios2, and riscv) no longer have a `readlink` system call, and the function as to be implemented using `readlinkat`.  This implementation is in the file `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/readlink.c`.

It's not clear what you are doing so that the wrong file is compiled.  Are you sure you have installed compatible kernel headers?

The particular [upstream commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=95b7042bac3e2cfc6fef7aec6acc7d46dd50eba5) (which went into glibc 2.15):

```
commit 95b7042bac3e2cfc6fef7aec6acc7d46dd50eba5
Author: Roland McGrath <roland@hack.frob.com>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 10:02:42 2011 -0800

    Fix __readlink declaration.
```

But given the fundamental nature of the build problem you encountered, I doubt that applying this patch, while addressing the immediate build failure, will give you a functional glibc build in the end.

Answer (score 0):

GLIBC : 2.14 →  2011-06-01. The "bugfix version" 2.14.1 → 2011-10-07 https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/

Note : `make -j4` is not recommended for glibc, as far as I remember.

My tests (old SLE11 SP2) : The SLE 11 SP2 gcc 4.3.2 is too old for glibc-2.14.1, may be the SP3 minor gcc update (to 4.3.4) is also too old?

Using the "extra EL 6 gcc-4.9.3" .... for glibc-2.14.1 :

```
cd build-glibc214/     # the recommended build directory outside the glibc source
export CC=gcc49 CXX=g++49 && ../glibc-2.14.1/configure --prefix=/opt/glibc214
make             # no errors
# make install   # OK
```

Extra gcc´s : [how to install gcc 4.9.2 on RHEL 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175706/how-to-install-gcc-4-9-2-on-rhel-7-4/47189915#47189915)