# GLIBC-2.14 is not visible after installation

Tags: installation, version, redhat

i referred this doc: [How to upgrade glibc from version 2.12 to 2.14 on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616650/how-to-upgrade-glibc-from-version-2-12-to-2-14-on-centos)

to install glibc-2.14 on my redhat machine.

but after installation, i am not able to see the new istalled version.

command: ldd --version
output: glibc-2.12

command rpm -q glibc
output: glibc-2.12

i have tried yum  update glibc as well but get same result.